# How to rebase from parent branch?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

Below is the current scenario of branch `X` & `Y` in Git:

```
   A - B [origin/master]
     \
      C - D - G - H [origin/X]
           \
            E - F [Y]
```

---

where,

developer1 is working on branch `X`

and

am working on branch `Y`.

`X` is parent branch of `Y`.

---

Currently branch `Y` is pointing remotely to `origin/Y`

I want to include changes of `origin/X` in branch `Y` before working further on branch `Y`. So, I would like to see, something like:

```
A - B [origin/master]
     \
      C - D - G - H [origin/X]
                   \
                    E1 - F1 [Y]
```

---

1) What are the git commands for rebasing my branch `Y`?

2) What does this command(`git branch -u origin/X Y`) do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's simple:

```
git checkout Y
git rebase origin/X
```

That is, assuming you will do it *after* someone (the other developer) rebases X (I see it was rebased on top of master).

**Second question**: it creates a local branch Y that has "upstream" branch set to origin/X. Upstream is like the branch that Y will use as the base when you try commands like `git pull` or `git pull -r`.

Comment: Whether branch `X` owner rebased from `master` is branch `X` owner's problem. Branch `X` owner is not rebasing from `master` despite I suggested him. Branch `X` is 7-8 commits behind `master`. I just want to make sure that branch `X` lastest commit is in `Y`. Rest is management's problem.

Comment: Follow up on  second question: Does `git push` pushes changes to `origin/X`?

Comment: Well... from the point of view of the end result, you would get the same thing if you merge or rebase... but rebase allows you to get changes from other branches by _moving_ your revisions to be on top of the other branch... instead of merging two separate branches on a single merge revision. Think of a feature branch. If you develop, merge, develop more, then merge... then develop more then merge, what would be required if you wanted to move that feature to an unrelated branch (think, backporting that feature). YOu would need to cherry-pick the revisions **without** the merges....

Comment: ... If you had used rebases instead, you would get your feature in a single line that can be moved around (**rebased**) rather easily.

Comment: Yes, if you tried to push (without saying anything else), it would try to push on upstream branch.

Comment: so local branch `Y` will point to remote's `origin/X` after running this command(`git branch -u origin/X Y`)

Comment: Careful with the word "point". It can mean veeeery different things for different people. If you mean, the branch points to the same **revision** (the way branches work on git)... then yes (but it won't be true after you commit something)... if you mean that branch Y will have origin/X as a kind of special branch it will relate to (the upstream), then yes (as explained, used when pulling/pushin).

Comment: Am bit confused between `git remote add origin` and `git branch -u` option. Are you saying `git checkout Y` will always pick from it's `origin/Y`?

Comment: Well... those are completely different things. A remote is just telling a local repo of _another_ repo where you will get branches and tags (you add the remote, then fetch and you get all the info from that remote.. no local branches are created/moved/deleted with this). When you run `git branch -u` you are setting up a new local _branch_ and you will also specify the branch that it will use as its upstream branch.

Comment: If you _do not_ have a preexisting local Y branch created and you run `git checkout Y` git will try to see if there's one (and only one) remote branch called Y around. If there is only one remote branch called Y, it will create a _local_ branch called Y and will set the remote branch as its upstream.

Comment: I have done one peculiar thing after creating branch `Y` from branch `X`. As I know that  branch `Y` is not make changes to the files that branch `x` is making, so, I deleted those files in branch `Y`, for the reason that  these files will be back in branch `Y` after rebase with minimal conflicts. Make sense?

Comment: Nope.... not gonna work. Deleting a file is an operation that git will keep track of so when you rebase it will try to delete the file on the rebase operation (which is probably not what you want)... also, if the file has been modified on the other branch, you will get a tree conflict.

Comment: It's not like you can not delete files on branches. It's valid to do it.... if it makes sense to what you are developing on your feature branch. If what you want to do is, I don' t know... reduce visual noise by not seeing those files around on the FS... or same some space, you are doing it wrong. You will have a hard time later when you try to rebase or merge. Then the question will be "why was the file removed?"

Comment: I removed the file completely because, keeping that file for rebase will have lot of line changes during rebase.... Do you suggest me to create those files? in branch `Y` before rebase?

Comment: Like, you already deleted the files (not related to your topic branch development) on your feature branch? Sure... get them back or you will have a hard time later on. Actually, if the changes haven' t been pushed yet, you should amend those revisions where you deleted them so that _it never happened_.

Comment: Rebase does not involve changing stuff that you actually don't change. If you don't touch a file, it won't be a problem when rebasing or merging.

Comment: If no one else has used the branch (it's only yours, hasn't been merge yet) you can still rewrite branch history and force-push to remove those file deletions..... but that's a completely different topic/question altogether.

Comment: Upvoted the answer, not only for its accuracy but for the sustained support in comments :-) Ha, what a dedication!

Comment: @RomainValeri hahaha

Comment: Gotta take advantage of not seeing torek or you around to answer questions :-D